# How to convert unicode code character variable to unicode character in python2

Tags: unicode

I know

```
if input 

  word=u"\uff21"

  print word

, return

  A

.
```

But now I have a variable

```
 word="\uff21"
```

I want "A" next.

How??

Please help.

Comment: `'\uff21'.decode('unicode_escape')`

Answer (score 0):

In python3, `"\uff21"` without the `'u' - unicode symbol` will directly give you the unicode equivalent. either typing `"\uff21"` or `print("\uff21")` will return an `'A'` as result.

In python2 you can pass it in to this function
`chr(ord("\uff21"))`.

One-character Unicode strings can  be created with the `chr()` built-in function, which takes integers and returns a Unicode string of length 1 that contains the corresponding code point. The reverse operation is the built-in `ord()` function that takes a one-character Unicode string and returns the code point value: